# how to show store position and user position on embedded map

Tags: dictionary, coordinates

i have store's latitude and longitude in database . How to show the store and user coordinates both coordinates on embedded map in php

```
$latitudeFrom = '6.160891';
$longitudeFrom = '1.2713296';


$latitudeTo = $row['lat'];
$longitudeTo = $row['lng'];
```

++".$Adresse.""; ?>&layer=off&hl=fr&source=s_d&hl=en&z=18&output=embed">

Comment: What map product do you mean?